# What is wrong with this highcharts.js code?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Here's the highcharts demo for a heatmap:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/heatmap/

...and here's the example I'm working on with my own data:

http://jsfiddle.net/conorgriffin/t44mP/1/

1. Why are my squares only rendering in shades of blue when the value goes into the range where they should be yellow?
2. Why are only two colours rendered on the scale when I have coded the following `colorAxis` values?

   ```
   colorAxis: {
       stops: [
           [0, '#3060cf'],
           [10, '#fffbbc'],
           [20, '#c4463a']
       ],
       min: 0
   }
   ```

## HTML code:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

## JavaScript Code:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'heatmap',
            marginTop: 40,
            marginBottom: 40,
        },

        title: {
            text: '<b>Enterprise Data Services: Errors per service per device today</b>'
        },

        xAxis: {

            categories: ['STAGEESB1', 'STAGEESB2', 'STAGEESB3',
                         'STAGEESB4', 'STAGEESB5', 'STAGEESB6'],
            title: 'Service'
        },

        yAxis: {
            categories: ['EnterpriseDSReferenceV1.0.0', 
                         'EnterpriseDSCustomer_A', 
                         'EnterpriseDSProduct_A', 
                         'EnterpriseDSGeography_A',
                         'EnterpriseDSDMSOrganizationCUD'],
            title: 'Device'
        },

        colorAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0, '#3060cf'],
                [10, '#fffbbc'],
                [20, '#c4463a']
            ],
            min: 0
        },

        legend: {
            align: 'right',
            layout: 'vertical',
            margin: 0,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            symbolHeight: 320
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + 
                    this.series.xAxis.categories[this.point.x] +
                    '</b> had <b>' + this.point.value + '</b> errors on <br><b>' +
                    this.series.yAxis.categories[this.point.y] + '</b>';
            }
        },

        series: [{
            borderWidth: 0,
            data: [[0,0,10],[0,1,19],[0,2,8],[0,3,24],[0,4,67],
                   [1,0,92],[1,1,58],[1,2,78],[1,3,117],[1,4,48],
                   [2,0,35],[2,1,15],[2,2,123],[2,3,64],[2,4,52],
                   [3,0,72],[3,1,132],[3,2,114],[3,3,19],[3,4,16],
                   [4,0,38],[4,1,5],[4,2,8],[4,3,117],[4,4,115],
                   [5,0,88],[5,1,32],[5,2,12],[5,3,6],[5,4,120]],
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: 'white',
                style: {
                    textShadow: 'none',
                    HcTextStroke: null
                }
            }
        }]

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually due to the stops.  They're value/1.0 on the scale from min to max.  So the code below works:

```
    colorAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0, '#3060cf'],
            [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
            [0.9, '#c4463a']
        ],
        min: 0
    }
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/conorgriffin/t44mP/2/